# How to add Anypoint Exchange repository url to JFrog Remote Repos

Tags: maven, mule, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I created a simple app specification in design center and published to exchange. we are using JFrog Artifactory

So to pull the raml from exchange I need to add the anypoint-exchange repository url in our JFrog Remote Repos.

When i tried to add https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven or https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/maven am getting 400 Bad Request .

How can i add anypoint-exchange url to our Jfrog Artifactory and get it fixed.

Comment: looks like it cannot be done as per this one https://help.mulesoft.com/s/ideas#08734000000HYKVAA4 ..

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the link you shared in the comments, you can't because Anypoint Exchange is not really a full Maven repository implementation. It simulates only the features required to publish assets and deploy to Anypoint Runtime Fabric. It doesn't currently implement the parts required to work as a remote repository or a Maven proxy.